# XML formatting comes out wrong

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to make an XML document through C# with a specific format, but I am having trouble getting it to look right. Here is what it comes out as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<loanRequest d1p1:ssn=""
d1p2:creditScore=""
d1p3:loanAmount=""
d1p4:loanDuration=""
xmlns:d1p4="26-08-2015 12:41:11"
xmlns:d1p3="147862"
xmlns:d1p2="266"
xmlns:d1p1="765383-2478" />
```

Here is what it should have been:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LoanRequest>
 <ssn>765383-2478</ssn>
 <creditScore>266</creditScore>
 <loanAmount>147862</loanAmount>
 <loanDuration>2015-08-26 12:41:11.0 CET</loanDuration>
</LoanRequest>
```

XML manipulation in C# is really confusing to me and I have a hard time piecing together how to do it. The code that I use to make the XML document is as follows:

```
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlNode docNode = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", null);
    doc.AppendChild(docNode);
    XmlNode loanRequest = doc.CreateElement("loanRequest");
    XmlAttribute ssn = doc.CreateAttribute("ssn", l.SSN);
    XmlAttribute creditscore = doc.CreateAttribute("creditScore", ""+l.CreditScore);
    XmlAttribute loanamount = doc.CreateAttribute("loanAmount", ""+l.LoanAmount);
    XmlAttribute loanduration = doc.CreateAttribute("loanDuration", l.LoanDuration.ToString());
    loanRequest.Attributes.Append(ssn);
    loanRequest.Attributes.Append(creditscore);
    loanRequest.Attributes.Append(loanamount);
    loanRequest.Attributes.Append(loanduration);
    doc.AppendChild(loanRequest);
```

Comment: Why are you creating attributes if you want elements?

Comment: @BenRobinson I don't quite understand C# XML manipulation. I wrote that in the question :P

Comment: I recommend looking at Linq-to-XML for a more fluent XML API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use Linq to Xml

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                 new XComment("this is a comment"),
                 new XElement("LoanRequest",
                      new XElement("ssn", l.SSN),
                      new XElement("creditScore", l.CreditScore),
                      new XElement("loanAmount", l.LoanAmount),
                      new XElement("loanDuration", l.loanDuration.ToString())));

doc.Save(path);
```

Comment: Thank you. I did what you said and then got a helper function to turn it into an XmlDocument and then get the `InnerXml` from that, to get the correct format. I am only missing the duration now. I can only get full date, or full time and if I call `ToString()` on the `DateTime` object itself, I only get sort-of what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you add as attributes what should be nodes. Replace the calls of `CreateAttribute` with calls of `AppendChild`.

Comment: But that only leaves me with a String for a name. How do I add the value?

Comment: The class `XmlNode` has a `Value` prpoerty, as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.value%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This makes no sense to me. `var ssn = doc.CreateElement("ssn").Value = l.SSN;` ???

Comment: No, more like `var ssn = doc.CreateElement("ssn"); ssn.Value = l.SSN;`

Comment: I get an error: `Additional information: Cannot set a value on node type 'Element'.` at `ssn.Value = l.SSN;`

Comment: My mistake; don't use `CreateElement` but use `AppendChild` on `doc`, which is documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: There is also a small tutorial here which might help http://forums.asp.net/t/1407620.aspx?Good+Example+of+how+to+create+a+Xml+Document+Programmatically+